# Opencv: how does the 'centers' parameter work in cv::kmeans?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, k-means, opencv3.0

I'm clustering points using kmeans with C++. The clustering and the plotting of each point work well, I can get something like this:

[image]

but I am not able to access the centers of each cluster (I want to plot them). How can I get the centers positions without computing them by myself?

I call the function in this way:

```
vector<Point2f> points;
...
// clustering
int K = 4; // number of clusters
Mat labels; // cluster each point belongs to
Mat centers; // center of each cluster
kmeans(points, K, labels, TermCriteria( TermCriteria::EPS+TermCriteria::COUNT, 50, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

and I plot them in this way:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++ ){
      int clusterIdx = labels.at<int>(i);
      Point ipt = points[i];
      circle(cluster_image, ipt, 10, colorTab[clusterIdx], -1, 8);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the the content of your centers matrix.

```
Size2i centersSize = centers.size();
std::list<Poind2f> centerPoints;
for(int i=0; i<centers.size(0); i++) {
    Point2f pt = centers.row(i);
    centerPoints.push_back(pt);
}
```

Even though the code above is untested, I hope it clarifies the idea.

Comment: Can you add some code showing how to leverage the data in the centers matrix?